unexpected behaviour of dispatching action in redux
I have the following async thunk function:
const loadProject = createAsyncThunk(
  '[Project API] Load Project',
  async (project: IKProject, { dispatch }) => {
    await kProjectService.loadProject(project)

    localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, project)
    dispatch(projectActions.setLoadedProject(project))

    // Loading & saving the project configuration
    const config = await kProjectService.getProjectConfig(project)
    dispatch(projectActions.setProjectConfig(config))
  }
)

const unLoadProject = createAsyncThunk(
  '[Project API] Un Load Project',
  async (project: IKProject, { dispatch }) => {
    await kProjectService.closeProject(project)
    dispatch(projectActions.resetState())
  }
)

const refreshProject = createAsyncThunk(
  '[Project API] Refresh Project',
  async (project: IKProject, { dispatch }) => {
    await dispatch(projectActions.unLoadProject(project))
    await dispatch(projectActions.loadProject(project))

    console.log('After refreshing')
  }
)

Project service:
import { IKProject, IKProjectConfig } from '@/Types'
import { httpService } from './http.service'

function loadProject(project: IKProject): Promise<IKProject> {
  return httpService.post(`/project/load`, project)
}

function loadProjectConfig(project: IKProject): Promise<IKProjectConfig> {
  return httpService.get(`/project/config`, project)
}

function closeProject(project: IKProject): Promise<unknown> {
  return httpService.delete(`/project/${project.name}/close`, project)
}

export const kProjectService = {
  loadProject,
  loadProjectConfig,
  closeProject,
}

Project slice looks like that
const projectSlice = createSlice({
  name: '[Project API]',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    resetState: () => initialState,
    setLoadedProject: (state, action: PayloadAction<IKProject | null>) => {
      state.kLoadedProject = action.payload
    },
    setProjectConfig: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<IKProjectConfig | null>
    ) => {
      state.kConfig = action.payload
    },
    reducers...
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(projectActions.refreshProject.pending, (state) => {
        state.isRefreshing = true
      })
      .addMatcher(
        isAnyOf(
          projectActions.refreshProject.rejected,
          projectActions.refreshProject.fulfilled
        ),
        (state) => {
          state.isRefreshing = false
        }
      )
  },
  selectors: {
    selectors...
  }
})

the isRefreshing in the initialState sets to false by default.
According to the defined extraReducers it's automatically changing based on the status of the promise (thunk function), now the issue that I'm facing is that when the refreshProject action executed it resolved immediately instead of waiting for the other's actions to finish.
after debugging, I do see the isRefreshing changing from false -> true -> false
NOTE: I do see the output of console.log('After refreshing') after the loadProject action is finished and this is why I don't get why the thunk is resolved immediately.
Please help.

"I don't get why the thunk is resolved immediately" - Perhaps there is nothing to actually await with the unLoadProject and loadProject action creators, and so everything is immediately settled. Unfortunately we can't say anything about these actions because we can't see what they do. If you would like more help then I think an [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with would be helpful.

that's because it does not matter, they all the same, createAsyncThunk, and async..., anyway I added them

Ok, so again, perhaps there's nothing to wait for. What do kProjectService.loadProject and kProjectService.closeProject and the other "// some more actions later and awaits" do? Do these functions do actual asynchronous work? This is what a complete [mcve] should show us.

Yes, both, the return value is an axios (HTTP request), like axios.get(url...)

@DrewReese i have updated the post with all required code, should be easier now, please help

looks like the resetState() action in unLoadProject caused the problem here.
resolved: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/4528
